# Create a command line script

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal

I'm using a web tool that has inbound webhooks. They provide me with a URL, to which I can POST a string and it logs it into the system.

I would like to create a script that me and my team can use from the terminal to do something like this:

```
~: appName 
~: What is the webHook URL?
```

Here I can copy and paste the URL gives me, and stores it.
Then from now I can do this:

```
~: appName This is a message that I want to send...
```

And this sends as a POST to the webhook the string. This would ideally something I can share with non-techies and that's easy to set up. And I have no idea how to even start this.

Comment: You can use `curl` to post to sites, and a [bash tutorial](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want this to be strictly shell.

In the end you want to use something like curl (bash)

```
curl --data "msg=$2" $url
```

The $url variable could come from a flat file(app.txt) that is just key value with key=appName

You first script would need to append to the file(app.txt)

```
echo $1 $2 >> app.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get started:

```
#!/bin/bash
msg=$1
url=""
[ ! -f webhookurl ] || url=`cat webhookurl` #webhookurl is a file where you put the url
if [ "$url" == "" ]; then
read -p "What is the webHook URL? " url
echo $url > webhookurl
fi

# Now start posting message

curl --data "msg=$msg" $url
```

save it with `appname`. Then run `appname` like this:

```
./appname "message to send"
```

It will ask for `url` for the first time and save it in `webhookurl` file in the same folder as the script for future use.

Comment: Is it possible to have it installed globally? If yes how?

Comment: For example, when I do `npm install app...`,`npm` works everywhere

Comment: Put the script in /usr/bin or /bin